# Call the maximum from SQL table to textbox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am working on a Windows Forms C# application and I need to auto generate my invoice number from my database. For that I need to get the maximum value from the database and want to add one with the max value in db, any idea

Comment: Where do you want the value? In database or front end?

Comment: `max from one table into other try this`select max(values) into table(values) from my_db

Comment: I need in front end. to be viewed on a textbox.

Comment: **Do not do this!** This is **NOT** reliable! If multiple users are using your application, sooner or later, you will have duplicates! Let the database handle this - use `INT IDENTITY` in SQL Server or whatever other "auto-increment" mechanism your database has to deal safely with determining unique numbers!

Comment: i am not good in SQL coding so can any one help me to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could design your database table using an `IDENTITY` column. The database will assign a next value for the inserted row. You can access the value using one of: `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, `@@IDENTITY` or `IDENT_CURRENT`. More can be found here: [MSDN-Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To know the difference between `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `@@IDENTITY` see [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Max(ColumnName) + 1 to get the Next Record.

```
Select Max(ColumnName) + 1 From TableName
```

This Will Return the next ID Number.
Use SQLCommand and executeScalar to get that single value.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MAX(column) FROM table
```

will return the maximum value from 'column'. You really should consider using an auto increment for the invoice, though. If you have more than one user inserting a new record at the same time, they may get the same invoice number.

Answer (score -1):

Using `Max(column_name)` is the best one and alternate is ordering the required column by Descending and taking very first row by top 1.

you need to validate if there are no records/it is very first record.

Syntax:

```
Select top 1 Column_name from TableName Order by Column_Name desc
```

Usage Example:

```
Select top 1 INV_NUMBER from TRANSACTION Order by INV_NUMBER desc
```